# Querying the Sphinx Search Index

Tags: sphinx

I am using the Sphinx Search engine and I have an issue where a few files are not showing up in the search results and definitely should be.  I have checked to make sure no info. is missing that would prevent these files from appearing.

Is there some way for me to query the index directly to see if these records are in there, or to see whether or not a specific record is there?

I found a similar post on the subject:

[Sphinx Search Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400084/sphinx-search-index)

So, it appears it is possible to do, but that post is not detailed enough on how to do it.  I am not following what exactly is going on in that post, in other words.  Do I just put this directly into the command line?

Or is there a tutorial available on this?  I searched and could not locate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx provides connection through mysql's protocol, so you can use any of mysql's clients to connect and execute queries:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/programs-client.html

If you will install command-line client, you should connect like this:

```
$ mysql -h0 -P9306
```

Sphinx supports custom subset of SQL, called SphinxQL, you can use it to query data from index. There is documentation about SphinxQL:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/latest/sphinxql-reference.html